# Javascript: Automaticly Count and Display the Number of Words on a Web Page

Tags: javascript, count, numbers, cpu-word

I was wondering if anyone can assist me with this problem: I am trying to type in code that Automatically Counts and Displays the Number of Words on a Web Page using JavaScript.

I have searched stack overflow and the internet in general, and there does not seem to be any examples on this that can help.

Comment: `document.body.textContent.split(/\s/).length`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function countWords(){

var Element= document.getElementsByTagName("body");

 // Split the innerHtml .
 var count = Element[0].textContent.split(' ').length;

document.write("Number of words: "+count);
}

countWords();
```

Comment: This counts comments and tags, and attributes and their values (if containing spaces) in tags, as well as possible scripts in `body` as words too ; ).

Comment: yeah thanks, i think I should use textContent instead!

Comment: Well, actually comments and scripts are included with `textContent`, this really needs an algorithm. + I suppose OP is creating a browser extension or sth ...

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I don't appreciate the negativity I got from a simple question... >_>

Comment: it's ok! this happens you just need to know the proper way of asking questions, read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
var totwords = document.body.innerText.split(' ').length;
```

Comment: An answer solely consisting of code with no or little explanation makes it difficult to understand which approach the asker should take and why your answer is viable. Please add explanations to your code.